# ruby on rails on snow leopard

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried the rails site_name command to create a rails application. The command says that the usage is rails new APP_PATH[options]

I tried the rails new site_name command.
I dont get any server file inside my site_name/script folder to run the application.
why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
$ rails server
```

to start the server. In general with Rails 3, any command you would have previously run with `./script/...` you now run with `rails ...`